# Delete 2 columns based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an Access function built to export a query to Excel. There are spaces for 15 results. Not all of them are used though, so I'd like to delete the blank columns.

I've been trying to search Lrow + 1 for "0.000" and then deleting the entire column, but it isn't working. 0.000 is a formula but I am using .Value method so that shouldn't be the problem, right?

Here's the code I tried to write (but failed miserably):

```
For Each Cel In wks.Range("C" & Lrow + 1, "V" & Lrow + 1)
If Cel.Value = "0.000" Then
Cel.EntireColumn.Delete
Cel.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Delete
End If
Next Cel
```

As in the picture, there are 2 results shown. This is what I would like to happen: Search lrow + 1 (the row with 0.000), delete those columns along with the column next to it.

Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: you should always loop backwards when deleting or gather qualifying ranges with Union and delete in one go.

Comment: And your range reference syntax is off: `"C" & Lrow + 1 & ":V" & Lrow + 1`. Though I'd loop right to left by column instead of using `For Each`.

Comment: How would I loop QHarr. I tried that BigBen, but still nothing happens. The extra columns are still there.

Comment: Why doesn't your export query discard these rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues here:

1. The range reference is wrong as Big Ben pointed out
2. The comparison is (probably) wrong.  I'm guessing the call values are numbers, not strings that look like numbers. So comparing `0` to `"0.000"`  will fail.  Use `= 0` or if you are worried about small not quite 0 numbers use `Absolute value <= 0.0005`
3. The delete logic is flawed, it won't delete the columns you think

.

```
Set rng = wks.Range("C" & Lrow + 1 & ":V" & Lrow + 1)
For i = rng.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
    If rng.Cells(1, i).HasFormula Then
        If Abs(rng.Cells(1, i)) <= 0.0005 Then
            Rng.Cells(1, i).Resize(1, 2).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Don't forget to use `Option Explicit` and declare all variables